# T-SQL loop through multiple views based mapping table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a multiple views where we need to get values from. There is one table in SQL where the views and column names are mapped.

MappingTable:

```
| Id | ViewName | ViewColumnName   |
| ---+----------+------------------|
| 1  | vwCars   | MotorType        |
| 2  | vwCars   | FourWheelDrive   |
| 3  | vwCars   | TransmissionType |
| 4  | vwBikes  | MotorType        |
| 6  | vwBikes  | TransmissionType |
| 7  | vwQuads  | MotorType        |
| 9  | vwQuads  | FourWheelDrive   |
| 16 | vwQuads  | TransmissionType |
```

I have created a T-SQL query that goes through every combination like this an gets the value needed:

```
select distinct MotorType from vwCars where MotorType is not null
union
select distinct FourWheelDrive from vwCars where FourWheelDrive is not null
union
...
```

This is the query:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @i int = 0;
declare @j int = (select max(Id) from MappingTable);
declare @ViewName nvarchar(80);
declare @ViewColumnName nvarchar(80);

while(@i < @j + 1)
    begin
            set @ViewName = (select ValueView from MappingTable where Id = @i);
            set @viewColumnName = (select ValueColumn from MappingTable where Id = @i);
                    if (select 1 from MappingTable where Id = @i) = 1
                        set @sql += 'select distinct cast(' + @ViewColumnName + ' as nvarchar(80)) as Bezeichnung from ' + @ViewName + ' where ' + @ViewColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL
                        ';
                        if (select 1 from MappingTable where Id = @i) = 1 and (@i < @j) set @sql += 'union
                ';
            set @i = @i + 1;
    end;
print(@sql);
```

The biggest problem was to get through everything also when there are spaces in Id. Query works, however I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: *" I was wondering if there is a better way"* Not using a `WHILE` would be better, in my opinion.

Comment: Alter the mapping table and change ID type to int so you will not have spaces there.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: FIxing your design would probably be the best option. Why are you storing your data in so many separate view/tables in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

No need for the while loop. try something like this:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max) = ''
SELECT  @s = @s + 'select distinct ' + ViewColumnName + ' from ' + viewname + ' where ' + ViewColumnName + ' is not null
UNION '
FROM    MappingTable
SET @s = LEFT(@s, LEN(@s)-8)
print @s
```